# Configuration mechanism to flag the attributes of an object that should be synchronized

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm refactoring a very old Java application. It has a component which is responsible for synchronizing a complex object with an object of the same type from a different source. The object has a lot of attributes (nearly hundred) of different types, including class types, which in turn have a lot of attributes.

I want to have the feature to tell the component which attributes of the object should be synchronized or not. My first idea was dependency injection. But what should I inject? I don't want to have an interface with methods like `public boolean shouldSynchronizeAttributeA()`, `public boolean shouldSynchronizeAttributeB()` etc. for every attribute including the attributes of the compositions of the objects. How would you solve this issue in a nice and maintainable way?

Comment: Why not just use a `String[]` with attribute (or rather property) names (perhaps with some ognl/mvel)

Comment: What is your exact definition of "to synchronize"? I could imagine marking the attributes with an [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html).

Comment: I cant change the classes, so adding annotations is not an option. "To synchronize" means to bring a persisted object up-to-date by updating its attributes. I have an object persisted in a database. Several clients can update this object and send theor changes to a server. The server then decides if and what attributes of the persisted object should be overwritten with the changes. The list of updated attributes the server checks should be configurable. Making the list of attributes to be synchronized configurable is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using strings and [mvel](https://github.com/mvel/mvel). There are many other libraries available (e.g, ognl). You could even use something like orika (i am not familiar with. I used dozer many years ago)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final SomeClass o1 = new SomeClass();
    o1.setAddress(new Address("Paris"));

    final SomeClass o2 = new SomeClass();
    o2.setAddress(new Address("London"));

    System.out.println(o2.getAddress().getCity()); // shows London
    synchronise(o1,o2,"address.city");
    System.out.println(o2.getAddress().getCity()); // shows Paris

}

private static <T> void synchronise(final T o1, final T o2, final String path) {

    final String SOURCE = "source";
    final String TARGET = "target";

    final Map<String,T> c = new TreeMap<String, T>();

    c.put(SOURCE,o1);
    c.put(TARGET,o2);

    final ParserContext parserContext = new ParserContext();

    final String expr = TARGET + "." + path + "=" + SOURCE  + "." + path;

    final CompiledExpression compiledExpression = new ExpressionCompiler(expr, parserContext).compile();


    MVEL.executeExpression(compiledExpression,c );


}
```

The examples classes:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}

public class Address {
    private String city;

    public Address(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```